# Associative array to CSV where columns are dynamic

Tags: php, csv, dynamic, associative-array

Given an array such as this:

```
[
    [
        'first_name' => 'Bill',
        'last_name' => 'Johnson',
        'telephone' => '123-456-7890'
    ],
    [
        'first_name' => 'Kurtis',
        'last_name' => 'Wild',
        'telephone' => '321-654-0987'
    ],
    [
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'email' => 'janedoe@gmail.com'
    ]
]
```

I need to be able to write a CSV like so:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
| first_name | last_name |  telephone   |       email       |
+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
| Bill       | Johnson   | 123-456-7890 |                   |
| Kurtis     | Wild      | 321-654-0987 |                   |
| Jane       | Doe       |              | janedoe@gmail.com |
+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

The difficult part is that the `telephone` and `email` columns are dynamic. They exist for some rows but not others, and there can be any number of these fields that exist only on a subset of rows. All of the rows that *do* share a certain field need to have that field in the same column positioning. The rows that *do not* have this field should just have empty cells.

I guess what I'm looking for is a generic way to take an associative array as shown above and dump out a string representing a CSV that uses the array keys as headers, keeping in mind they will not match across rows.

I have already tried passing such an array into [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), and also tried the [`league/csv`](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) package, but neither of these support this. Does anybody know a library that can do this, or perhaps even just a function that can take this type of array and spit out a correct CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of `foreach` loops will work if you want to keep it dynamic:

```
# Create a key storage array
$cols   =   [];
foreach($arr as $row) {
    foreach($row as $k => $v) {
        if(!in_array($k, $cols))
            $cols[$k] =   '';
    }
}
# Loop the main array again and merge the storage array
foreach($arr as $k => $row) {
    $arr[$k]    =   array_merge($cols, $row);
}
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Bill
            [last_name] => Johnson
            [telephone] => 123-456-7890
            [email] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Kurtis
            [last_name] => Wild
            [telephone] => 321-654-0987
            [email] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Jane
            [last_name] => Doe
            [telephone] => 
            [email] => janedoe@gmail.com
        )

)
```

If you want to just manually create the reference array, you can easily merge a blank array with the populated array and get a mixed array:

```
$cols   =   [
    'first_name' => '',
    'last_name' => '',
    'email' => '',
    'telephone' => ''
];

foreach($arr as $k => $row) {
    $arr[$k]    =   array_merge($cols, $row);
}
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Bill
            [last_name] => Johnson
            [email] => 
            [telephone] => 123-456-7890
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Kurtis
            [last_name] => Wild
            [email] => 
            [telephone] => 321-654-0987
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Jane
            [last_name] => Doe
            [email] => janedoe@gmail.com
            [telephone] => 
        )
)
```

EDIT:

I am  not sure if you needed an array to CSV function, but here's just a quick one:

```
function downloadCSV($rows)
{
    ob_start();
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($rows as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    $str    =   ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.date('YmdHis').'file.csv"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($str));
    echo $str;
    exit;
}
```

So after you have your array from one of the above-mentioned methods, just run this function before any other browser output:

```
# $arr being your array of course
downloadCSV($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is essentially what I ended up doing. used array_keys() to get all the columns, made sure that each row in the CSV has the same columns, then sorted the entire set, then used fputcsv() to write.